# in which maven life cycle, dependencies get downloaded from maven central repository to my local .m2 repository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Generally i follow below maven commands to build and run my project.

1. mvn clean
2. mvn clean verify
   or
3. mvn clean install
4. mvn spring-boot:run

My doubt is in which maven life cycle, dependencies get downloaded from maven central repository to my local .m2 repository.

I went through below mentioned maven life cycle but no where i found that **in this steps dependency gets downloaded**.

1. validate
2. compile
3. test
4. package
5. verify
6. install
7. deploy

Please explain it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a maven project, before validate there is step 'prepare-resources' which copies resources. Also when you do maven clean it will download dependencies. Read this link for more details

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_life_cycle.htm

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here of `prepare-resources` is incorrect. That may be confusing the downloading of Maven plugins and their dependencies, but not the project's dependencies.

They actually are downloaded during the `compile` lifecycle.

Here is an example of a project where the only dependency is GSON, and I just finished running the `process-resources` lifecycle, [the one that immediately precedes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#default-lifecycle) `compile` lifecycle. The only things present in my `.m2/repository` directory are things required by the default Maven plugins. Note that there is no `com` folder, which is where GSON would have been downloaded to.

[image: A few folders in .m2/repository, but no com folder]

After running `mvn compile`, the next lifecycle, a lot more dependencies are downloaded, including GSON:

[image: A com folder is now present]